# Application of finite intersection property

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

If $\mathscr{F}$ be a family of compact sets with finite intersection property in a metric space (X, d). Then show that $\cap \mathscr{F} \neq \phi$.
My thinking:  I want to prove by contradiction.
Let,  $\cap \mathscr{F} = \phi$    Then {$X-F: F\in \mathscr{F}$} is an open cover of X.
I don't know what to do next. If, I am on the right track, then, please somebody help me. Any independent idea is also welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW in LaTex when a "function" like \mathscr or \sqrt is to be applied to a solo key-stroke, you do not need brace-brackets. You can type \mathscr F and \sqrt x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right general idea, but you need to refine it a bit. Pick any $F_0\in\mathscr{F}$, and consider

$$\big\{X\setminus F:F\in\mathscr{F}\setminus\{F_0\}\big\}\;;$$

this is an open cover of the **compact** set $F_0$. Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Brian M. Scott as you have given me the hints, now I'm writing this in response. Please correct me if I am wrong.
            Now there will be a finite subcover of $F_0$. Let {$X-F_1$,$X-F_2$,...,$X-F_n$}be that finite subcover. Then $F_0$ $\subseteq$ $\cup (X-F_i) $ for i=1,2,...,n.   Which implies $F_0$ $\subseteq$  ($X - \cap F_i$) for i=1,2,...,n.  Which implies that $F_0 \cap F_i = \phi$ for i=1,2,...,n. Which contradicts finite intersection property . So, the assumption was wrong.

I'm sorry for I'm writing this in answer. Because after 5 minutes I am not able to put this in comment. I hope this is forgivable.

Comment: It’s almost right, but not quite. Since $F_0\subseteq X\setminus\bigcap_{i=1}^nF_i$, we have $F_0\cap\bigcap_{i=1}^nF_i=\varnothing$, i.e., $\bigcap_{i=0}^nF_i=\varnothing$, which contradicts the F.I.P. We cannot conclude, however, that $F_0\cap F_i=\varnothing$ for each $i=1,\ldots,n$: we just know that the intersection of **all** of them is empty.

Comment: OK, I get it. Thanks

Comment: You’re welcome.